# INSERT INTO a table with serial using SELECT *

Tags: postgresql, insert

In Postgres, I have a table with many columns (e.g. t1(a, b, c, ..., z)). I need to obtain its subset through a select-from-where statement into a new table (e.g. t2), but this new table must have a `serial` attribute. So, t2 would like t2(id, a, b, c, ..., z), where id the `serial` attribute. In Postgres, this works:

```
INSERT INTO t2(a, b, c, d, ..., z)
SELECT * 
FROM t1 
WHERE <condition>
```

However, is it possible to achieve the same without writing all the attributes of t1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a view that is a simple `SELECT` of all but the `serial` column.

Such views are updateable in PostgreSQL, so you can use it as the target for your `INSERT`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Laurenz's answer, it's worth noting that you can call the next value for each record in your serial sequence within your insert.

One way you could do it requires that you know the name of your sequence beforehand. By default the naming convention for a serial sequence will be `tablename_id_seq` where `tablename` in this case would be `t2`.

```sql
INSERT INTO t2
SELECT
    nextval('t2_id_seq')
  , t1.*
FROM t1
```

---

For more details on dealing with sequences:

Auto-generated sequences will adhere to the pattern `${table}_${column}_seq`.

You can find all sequences by running the following queries:

```sql
/* Version 10+ */
SELECT
  *
FROM pg_sequences -- Not to be confused with `pg_sequence`
WHERE sequencename LIKE '%t2%'
;

/* Version 9.5+ */
-- Returns the sequences associated with a table
SELECT 
  pg_get_serial_sequence('schema.tablename', 'columnname')
;

-- Returns sequences accessible to the user, not those owned by the user
SELECT
  *
FROM information_schema.sequences
WHERE sequence_name LIKE '%t2%'
;

-- Return sequences owned by the current user
SELECT 
  n.nspname AS sequence_schema, 
  c.relname AS sequence_name,
  u.usename AS owner
FROM pg_class c 
  JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
  JOIN pg_user u ON u.usesysid = c.relowner
WHERE c.relkind = 'S'
  AND u.usename = current_user;

/* Version 8.1+ */
-- Returns sequences accessible to the user, not those owned by the user
SELECT 
  relname
FROM pg_class
WHERE relkind = 'S' -- 'S' for sequence
;
```

Comment: All I get is `ERROR:  DEFAULT is not allowed in this context` when using `DEFAULT`. Including exactly with your syntax.

Comment: Indeed, the DEFAULT does not work this way. The answer is wrong.